# Obtaining podcasts without using iTunes, how?

Tags: linux, podcasts

Is it possible to search for podcasts without using iTunes? I’m running Fedora so I would prefer not to have to install iTunes in [Wine](https://www.winehq.org).

Is there an application or plugin to RhythmBox that allows you to search for podcasts the same way as iTunes does? Maybe even connect to the same repository/listings of podcasts?

There are some podcasts I subscribe to that aren’t hosted on websites, so unless I can access them in an iTunes-like fashion, I can’t easilly get to them.

Comment: iTunes is poorly supported in wine, so I agree that that's a lousy solution. Can you give examples of podcasts that are in iTunes but not available online? That might help with searching for a solution.

It sounds like you already know this, but just in case, podcasts are generally implemented using XML feeds (example: http://americanpublicmedia.publicradio.org/podcasts/) iTunes-specific links seem to work the same way, but hide the XML file location from you.

Comment: Some more feed format info, directly from Apple: http://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/specs.html

Comment: An example is a podcast by some friends, http://3brothersradio.com/, they don't have it on their site but its in the iTunes podcast section. Can't find it on Podcast Alley either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Podcast Alley](http://www.podcastalley.com) lets you search for podcasts and provides you with the feeds.

Comment: Raven, thats a brilliant link, thanks for that. Although it doesn't seem to have "everything" that iTunes does, but certainly worth bookmarking ;)

Answer (score 3):

[Tunesviewer](http://tunesviewer.sf.net) will let you search, browse, and download iTunes podcasts.

> TunesViewer is a small, easy to use program to access itunes-university media and podcasts in Linux.
>
> **Features:**
>
> - Direct searching, browsing, and downloading.
> - Supports itunes-University login, to download students-and-staff-only media.
> - Reveals the standard rss-podcast-feed of the itunes-podcasts, for use in any podcast software.
> - Includes the option to set itself as default protocol handler, to go directly from the "loading itunes-U..." page to viewing with TunesViewer.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Rhythmbox actually searches iTunes when you go to the podcast section and search.

On the left, just select Podcasts, add, and then enter search terms.